# Is there a package manager that offers recent boost/clang/cmake versions AND creates references and env. variables? (18.04)

Tags: 18.04, package-management, cmake, boost, clang

I need at least clang 7+, boost 1.77+, cmake 3.11+ on Ubuntu 18.04 and I am too dumb to install them manually because I do not know where to install, what to link and which env. variables to set. Therefore I want to ask, if there is a package manager, that does both:

1. Offer the above mentioned versions of tools and libraries
2. Installs everything it downloads in the right location and sets links, references, env. variables

I tried with pip, but the clang-7 I downloaded cant be found by cmake. If I download clang 6 with apt-get though it can be found by cmake.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: @guiverc sorry but does not really answer my question: I know why apt is ages behind current versions, but I ask for a smooth way to actually install recent software, no matter the "safety" or "reliability".

Comment: Your question does not specify why a four-year-old release (18.04) is important to you, so perhaps using an older release is an oversight and easily corrected. If you upgrade to 20.04, clang and cmake versions that you seek are trivial to install.

Comment: it's whats running on my vserver and I share it with other people who did put some effort into configuring stuff the way they need it.

Comment: Well, move those fancy configs to a 20.04 install to solve your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)